# Table spacing problem with {caption} package

Tags: spacing, captions, margins

I use the caption package for its possibility to reduce the figure and table caption margin and was happy with it. However, I just found out that it also causes some unwanted changes to the caption spacing.

My problem is best described with pictures. Here you can see the spacing of the caption **with** the caption package:

[image]

and

[image]

And now **without** the caption package:

[image]

and

[image]

As you can see in the images, the package either messes up the spacing of the figure or table, depending if I use it or not.

This is the code that I use:

```
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
```

Any ideas how I can prevent this inconsistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't mess up any spacing. It simply does what basic LaTeX should (and doesn't) do. 
Here is an explanation: two skips are associated to `\caption`: `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`. When the caption is  *below* the float, \abovecaptionskip has some value (`10pt`, if I remember well, in standard classes) and \belowcaptionskip is `0pt`. When the caption is *above* the float (normal position  for tables), these values should be exchanged.

Thus `caption` sets the *normal* behaviour: a small vertical skip between caption and float. Of course, if you think the skip is too large, you can  set it to another values, with

```
\captionsetup[table]{skip=6pt}
```

for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Bernard - I really like what the caption package does to the spacing in tables, but I don't like the reduced spacing in figures. So after reading your answer, what I want to do is to restore the default spacing for figures only. Do you know what the equivalent `{skip=Xpt}` is?

Comment: To add on my previous answer: You say `10pt` is the default. I presume this is _with_ the caption package, because without it the spacing looks a bit larger.

Comment: No, it is the default values in the `article`, `report` and `book` classes. In the case of figures, it may happen there's white spaces around the figure, and you may think this white space is part of the skip. To check, add a frame to your figure (e.g. with a simple `\fbox`) and measure the distance between  frame and caption (most pdf viewers have a tool for that).

Comment: [Here](https://s23.postimg.org/e56rgaqdn/Unbenannt.jpg) an image. I think one can see the difference in spacing with the bare eye (upper one is with caption package, lower one without). If I understand correctly, you're saying that in the lower one, some white space is part of the skip and with `\capture` this extra space is removed?